# No problem in debug apk, but in release apk "signInResult:failed code=12500" exception is found in GoogleSignInApi

Tags: java, android, google-signin

```
package com.oct2018.hiding_this;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
 private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
  private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;
    public String TAG="GOsign";
    private GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);
        Toast.makeText(this, "OnStart", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);GoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            Log.d(TAG,"RC_SIGN_IN");
            // The Task returned from this call is always completed, no need to attach
            // a listener.
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(task);
        }
    }
    // [END onActivityResult]
    // [START handleSignInResult]
    private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask) {
        try {
            GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);
            // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
            Toast.makeText(this, "SignIn Successfullly", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d(TAG,"Signedin Successfully");
        } catch (ApiException e) {
            // The ApiException status code indicates the detailed failure reason.
            // Please refer to the GoogleSignInStatusCodes class reference for more information.
            Log.w(TAG, "signInResult:failed code=" + e.getStatusCode())
        }
    }
    // [END handleSignInResult]
    // [START signIn]
    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }
    // [END signIn]
    // [START signOut]
    private void signOut() {
        mGoogleSignInClient.signOut()
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        // [START_EXCLUDE]
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "SignedOut", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        // [END_EXCLUDE]
                    }
                });
    }
    // [END signOut]
    // [START revokeAccess]
    private void revokeAccess() {
        mGoogleSignInClient.revokeAccess()
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        // [START_EXCLUDE]
                        //updateUI(null);
                        // [END_EXCLUDE]
                    }
                });
    }
    int i=0;
    public void login(View view)
    {
        if(i%2==0)
        signIn();
        else
            signOut();
        i++;
    }
}
```

> signInResult:failed code=12500

is always found when i try to sign in with my google account.(in release APK)

Comment: You probably put the debug SHA-1 into Firebase. You need the release SHA-1.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  A quick tip for entering code in a question - paste the code, select it and then click the `{}` icon. I submitted an edit for you, you should review it and make sure your indentation is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Update your Google Play Services to the latest version. In which device you are testing please check google play service version if not updated then update and try again.

You also need to configure with release sha-1 key in developer console.